# Infinite Background Image html/Css

Tags: html, css, image, background, infinite

I am creating a website in which i want there to be a background image. The image is black with some characters on it. The Page, however may be 'M' pixels tall (y axis) or 'N' pixels tall (y axis) .

I want only one instance of the image to be shown (not repetitive) How do I make it so that there is only one image at the top of the page and the rest of the page (however long it may be) is black?

Comment: Could you put your code on http://jsfiddle.net so we can see what you've attempted, thanks!

Comment: try using this in css: background-repeat: no-repeat;

Answer (score 2):

I would use:

```css
background: #000 url(pic.jpg) top center no-repeat;
```

***[See working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U5gY6/)***

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Eexb/1/)

```
body {
    height:2000px;
    background-image:url('http://www.acdc.com/sites/acdc/files/imagecache/1024x768/ACDC_Logo%5B1%5D.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:scroll;
    background-position:center top; 
    background-color:black;
}
```

If you want the image to stick into the top while scrolling, you can change the background-attachment rule to "fixed"...